# mplayer/mencoder fails encoding on a RHEL5 machine

Tags: mp3, lame, mplayer, mencoder

I'm using an application called ClipShare to post videos. However, encoding seems to fail. Here's what I get from the logs:

```
/usr/local/bin/mencoder /clipshare/video/39.wmv -o /clipshare/flvideo/39x.flv -of lavf -oac mp3lame -lameopts abr:br=56 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=flv:vbitrate=800:mbd=2:mv0:trell:v4mv:keyint=10:cbp:last_pred=3 -srate 22050  -ofps 25000/1001
MEncoder SVN-r32642-snapshot-4.1.2 (C) 2000-2010 MPlayer Team
get_path("config") problem
MPlayer was compiled without libmp3lame support.
-lameopts is not an MEncoder option

Exiting... (error parsing command line)
```

I do have LAME installed. If I run the command on the first line with the -nosound option it works, but with a lot of "skipping frame!"

Any ideas? I appreciate any help. Thanks!

-AC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that mplayer was installed in usr/local/bin instead of usr/bin. Problem solved!